# replacing ? by / and triming some text from url by htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hello all i am having a website where i have `htaccess` file the code inside the file seems like

```
 ErrorDocument 404 /error404.php
 ErrorDocument 403 /error404.php
 Options -Indexes 
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg)$ http://www.domain.com [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(page1)\.php\?eid=(78)[&\s] [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
 RewriteRule ^(page1)/(\d+)$ /$1.php?eid=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page2\.php\?url=([^\s&]+) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
      RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /page2.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The file successfully redirects the `page2.php?url=xyz` to `page2/xyz` but it directs the `page1.php?eid=3` to `page1?eid=3` besides this i also needs to direct the `page3.php?did=3` to `page3/3`

I need the `page2.php?eid=3` to be directed to `page2/3`
and `page3.php?did=4` to `page3/4`

`page1` is directed fine.
Can any one help me actually i am not so good in `htaccess` but i have tried to manipulate the `htacces` file but no help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what redirects you want? It is not clear parameter name is `did` or `eid` and page names are `page1` or `page2` or `page3`.

Comment: I need the page2.php?eid=3 to be directed to page2/3 and page3.php?did=4 to page3/4 .